# What to call a thing such as a balloon or tire that is in the process of losing its air inside it: It is deflating?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> [in‧flate](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/inflate) /ɪnˈfleɪt/ verb     1 Image of inflate[intransitive,
>   transitive] to fill something with air or gas so it becomes larger, or
>   to become filled with air or gas
>
> It took us half an hour to inflate the dinghy.
>
> Her life jacket failed to inflate.

---

> [de‧flate](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/deflate) /ˌdiːˈfleɪt, dɪ-/ verb
>
> 1 [intransitive, transitive] if a tyre, balloon etc deflates, or if
>   you deflate it, it gets smaller because the gas inside it comes out
>   OPP inflate → go down, let down
>
> Register
>
> In everyday British English, people usually say an object goes down
>   rather than deflates:
>
> It looks like the air bed has gone down.

---

Look at the picture

[image]

What to call a thing such as a balloon or tire that is in the process of losing its air inside it: "**the balloon is deflating**"?

And this picture

[image]

"**the balloon is fully inflated**"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking if "deflating" is the correct word for the action? It is. Do you mean something else?

Comment: @JKreft, yes, does the 1st picture show "the balloon is deflating"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding / usage of deflating seems to be correct. In the first picture, the balloon is deflating (if it is still losing air). Some might refer to it as a "deflated" balloon (emphasizing the past loss of air).

In the second picture, the balloon is "inflated". It is "fully inflated" if that is its intended maximum size.